# Python Spark output link to the job's web status page

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to "read" the configuration of the SparkContext to obtain a link to the job's and cluster's info pages?

In particular, how is it possible to get the port number (as the other info are rather straightforward to obtain)?

Comment: I hope someone knows a better way: `ui = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(sc._jsc).ui().get().appUIAddress()` ;)